# How to convert this dynamic index.html pages to a React page and connect it to the same Nodejs express page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I have a NodeJs backend and a React front end. The main problem I am facing is fetching the data from the React front end and sending it to the backend and wait while the Node js express backend executes. I am able to do this using a simple html page but not able to do it using React. Suggestions for the react is welcome. I am running NodeJs on port 4500 and React on port 3000.

Below I am attaching the HTML code and NodeJS code which is running perfectly when hosted on port 4500 and and giving result. But I need similar thing on my React. I am completely new to React, so I am struggling. Any help will be appreciated on the React front end page!

What I have to do is->

1. A simple text box with a submit button
2. After submitting, the Node js express backend executes with the submitted data.
3. The output will be a html table which I want to display in an iframe below the search box.

I am able to do it in html, js and Nodejs. But I want to do the front end in react js! Below I have written the React js code but not able to make it work.

Input HTML Page<index.html>

```
    <body>
        <div>
          <header>
            <h1>Project</h1>
          </header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="table-responsive">
          <form id="inputData" action="/search" method="POST" align="center">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="newItem"
            id="newItem"
            placeholder="What are you looking for?"
            width="50%"
            class="form-control"
          />
          <br/>
          <div align="center">
            <button type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="btn btn-info" ">Search</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <br/>
      </div>
      <footer>
        <p>Copyright ⓒ <span id="year"></span> Project</p>
      </footer>
      </div>
        <script>
          document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
          </script>
      </body>
```

Backend NodeJs page(server.js)

```
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const shelljs = require("shelljs");
    var cors = require("cors");

    const app = express();
    const { exec } = require("child_process");

    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.get("/", function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
    });

    app.post("/search", async function (req, res) {
      console.log("--------- Dirname -----" + __dirname);
      console.log("Entered the shell section");
      const data = req.body.newItem;
      exec(
        `cd /home/user/Desktop/Project/test; sh run.sh "${data}"`,    async (err, stdout, stderr) =>                         {
          if (err) console.error(err);
          console.log(stdout);
          exec("python3 csv_to_html.py", (err, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/search.html");
            console.log(":: End game ::");
          });
        }
      );
    });

    app.get("/output", function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + "/output.html");
    });

    app.listen(4500, function () {
      console.log("Server starting at port 4500...");
    });
```

Result Display HTML Page after executing the backend(search.html)

```
    <body>
        <div>
          <header>
            <h1>Project</h1>
          </header>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="table-responsive">
          <form id="inputData" action="/search" method="POST" align="center">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="newItem"
            id="newItem"
            placeholder="What are you looking for?"
            width="50%"
            class="form-control"
          />
          <br/>
          <div align="center">
            <button type="submit" name="button" id="button" class="btn btn-info" ">Search</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <div id="table">
        <iframe src="http://localhost:4500/output" frameborder="0" width="100%" class="myIframe">        
        </iframe>
        </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
        <p>Copyright ⓒ <span id="year"></span> Project</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
      <script>
          document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
      </script>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#table').show();
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      $(".myIframe").css("height", $(window).height() + "px");
    </script>
```

My code works absolutely fine when I run this on port 4500 and I am able to get the result.
I want to do the same thing with React Js as my front end and the same Node js express as my backend. I am not able to write a perfect React code. Here I am posting the code that I have written for the above HTML but not able to achieve the desired result. Can anyone help?

React Js Code<App.jsx>

```
    import React from "react";
    import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
    import axios from "axios";

    function App() {
      const year = new Date().getFullYear();
      return (
        <div>
          <header>
            <h1>Project</h1>
          </header>
          <div className="container">
            <form onSubmit={e => clickButton(e)}>
              <div className="form-group">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  id="searchData"
                />
              </div>

              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Search
              </button>
            </form>
            <br />
          </div>
          <footer>
            <p>Copyright ⓒ {year} Project</p>
          </footer>
        </div>
      );
    }

    function clickButton(e) {
      //alert("Works fine");
      //console.log("Works fine");
      e.preventdefault();
      let body = {
        newItem: document.getElementById("searchData").value
      };
     const postRequest = async () => {
         let res = await axios
           .post("http://localhost:4500/search", body)
           .then(response => {
             alert(response);

           })
           .catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error);
           });
       };
       postRequest();
    export default App;
```

Comment: Depending on the version of React you intend to use, have a look at [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) and [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). You seem to want to mix certain concepts here and that's never a good idea in the react world. Either you stick to react completely or you don't use it

Comment: Agreed with above. There’s a lot to unpack here. You’re not really using react here.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to create a link to the backend and get a response. I have written this code for convenience purpose of simply creating a link. After I am done with creating a link and getting a result, I will separate it into separate components. For now if you guys could help that would be great since I am new to using two separate servers and getting the result. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Basically I don't know how to use react as I am completely new to this. If anyone could help me, it will help clear my understanding of react.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a HashRouter or BrowserRouter. First have 2 pages for your react app, 1 for the index and another one for your search page. On you server side, simply return a success status. The react app can switch to the search page with window.location.href or window.location.hash after receiving the success status